# Send e-mail notification when an Asset is submitted for approval

Tags: content-management, content-hub

I want to be able to notify a user/ user group when an Asset is submitted for Approval.

Is there a way to do this without needing to create a script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an OOTB way to send emails to notify users about approval.

The only way is by creating the script.

The following script goes through the following high-level steps:

1. Check if a given named email template exists, and create a simple empty one, if it doesn’t
2. Retrieve the Content Managers Group
3. Retrieve all usernames from the group
4. Send notification email using the email template and retrieved usernames

```
using Stylelabs.M.Base.Querying;

using Stylelabs.M.Sdk.Contracts.Base;

using Stylelabs.M.Sdk.Contracts.Notifications;

using Stylelabs.M.Sdk.Models.Notifications;

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Globalization;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Linq;

    const string emailTemplatename = "Asset Acceptance Notification";
    
    SendEmailAsync();
    
    public async Task SendEmailAsync()
    {
    var rejectionTemplate = await MClient.Notifications.GetMailTemplateAsync(emailTemplatename);
    if (rejectionTemplate == null)
    {
    await CreateEmailTemaplateAsync();
    rejectionTemplate = await MClient.Notifications.GetMailTemplateAsync(emailTemplatename);
    }
    var groupId = MClient.Users.GetUserGroupAsync("Content Managers").Result.Id;
    var query = Query.CreateQuery(entities =>
    from e in entities
    where e.DefinitionName == "User"
    select e);
    var users = MClient.Querying.QueryAsync(query, new EntityLoadConfiguration { RelationLoadOption = RelationLoadOption.All}).Result;
    
    var groupUsers = new List<IEntity>();
    foreach(var user in users.Items)
    {    
        var groupRelation = user.GetRelation<IChildToManyParentsRelation>("UserGroupToUser");
        if (groupRelation.Parents.Contains(group.Id ?? 0)) // nullable ID, provide fallback
        {
            groupUsers.Add(user);
         }
    }
                
    var userNames = MClient.Users.GetUsernamesAsync(groupUsers.Select(i => i.Id ?? 0).ToList()).Result?.Select(i => i.Value).ToList();
    
    var notificationRequest = new MailRequestByUsername
    {
    MailTemplateName = emailTemplatename,
    Recipients = userNames
    };
    var entityModified = Context.Target as IEntity;
    notificationRequest.Variables.Add("AssetUrl", "https://somedomain.stylelabsdemo.com/en-us/asset/"+entityModified.Id);
    await MClient.Notifications.SendEmailNotificationAsync(notificationRequest);
    }
    public async Task CreateEmailTemaplateAsync()
    {
    var enUs = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
    var template = await MClient.EntityFactory.CreateAsync(Stylelabs.M.Sdk.Constants.MailTemplate.DefinitionName) as IMailTemplate;
    template.Name = emailTemplatename;
    template.SetSubject(enUs, "Asset Approved");
    template.SetBody(enUs, "Hello, the following asset got approved: {{AssetUrl}}");
    template.SetDescription(enUs, emailTemplatename);
    template.SetTemplateVariables(new[] {
    new TemplateVariable
    {
    Name = "AssetUrl",
    VariableType = TemplateVariableType.String
    }
    });
    await MClient.Entities.SaveAsync(template);
    }
```

You can view below link for more detail - https://www.cmsbestpractices.com/how-to-send-emails-in-sitecore-content-hub/